# Geronimo Server started but console not started

Tags: geronimo

I've an Apache Geronimo server which is started properly and I can see that there's no exception logged in geronimo.out or geronimo.log file.

But, when I try to access admin console. It gives HTTP 404 error.

Any pointer on what modules are missing during startup that is preventing console to start.

Thanks,

Vivek

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about you (your environment) but I have been running geronoimo on java 8 in Ubuntu 15.10 and 16.04 for a wile (adding a jre-8 section to config.properties) this has worked well for some time (including accessing console on http://localhost:8080/console/) but as you, I have now notices that the console is no longer accessible, I get a 403 error in browser but no clues in geronimo log on whats wrong.

Starting the server with java 7 the console is accessible and working again.

This leads me to suspect that resent java 8 updates or related libs(?) is causing the console to silently fail.

Comment: I am still stuck with a 403 error. Any luck on making it work?